# 405 Method is not Allowed exception: "Request Method 'T' not supported" for GET call and "Request Method 'ST' not supported" for POST

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-webclient

I am facing a very strange issue in my project. It is related to rest API call using spring reactive webclient bulider. It is working fine on local and prod as well but abnormally giving  below error  after 3 or 4 request to same endpoint.
"org.springframework.web.server.MethodNotAllowedException: 405 METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED "Request method 'T' not supported"
This is valid exception as method going to "T" for Get method and "ST" for Post method .I am not able to understand why two starting charcter truncating from method name

Please help me resolve this error.

Comment: can you add some code to understand this ?

Comment: You must post sample code to make your issue clear.

Comment: @Manuj did you ever figure this out? I'm having the exact same problem

Comment: @Manuj were u able to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

OP and I must have been the only ones to have ever experienced this and honestly I don't know the root cause but this was my situation and the fix.

For me, I was running 2 services in a docker. One service would make requests to the other. The 1st request always succeeds but the subsequent one always fails. After some time, a new request succeeds again.

I speculated that it must have to do with a persistent connection. I am using OkHttpClient library (3.14.9) to make the request. The service receiving the request was running spring webflux but I don't think the service was the issue. I could make repeated successful requests to it using curl from inside the 1st service's container.

OkHttpClient uses keep-alive connections by default. You can specify for a single request that you don't want to keep connection alive by setting the `Connection` header to `close`. Once I did that, all requests were working again.

For whatever reason, the re-use of the keep-alive connections was not sending over over and entire request. It was always truncating the first 2 characters of the method that is why `Request method 'T' not supported`. Perhaps the 1st request didn't end correctly and eats up the 2nd request's first 2 characters. I don't know the root cause. Probably a bug with OkHttpClient